# mediaplayer.getDuration() is throwing exception of illegalStateException in android 8.1, but working fine in lower versions

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I'm using Media Player in my android application, which plays audio files from given url. I also want to update progress bar while playing the audio file. For that I'm using seekbar.setMax(mediaplayer.getDuration()) in onPrepated() method, but mediaplayer.getDuration() is throwing exception of illegalStateException & showing mediaplayer state = 0 or 1 while same code is working for android 7 & lower versions

My code goes below :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("X-CSRF-Token",preferences.getString("token",null));
map.put("Cookie",preferences.getString("sessid",null));
map.put("Content-Type","application/json");


mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse(mediaUrl),map);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    seekBarProgress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);
    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
}


// method for updating seekbar

public void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater(final int i) {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && seekBarProgress != null) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.getDuration() > 0) {
                            seekBarProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    }
                    if (handler != null) {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](http://qaru.site/questions/10132471/fatal-exception-main-javalangillegalstateexception-when-press-back), postDelayed may causes the mediaPlayer to be in invalid state, so calling `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` will cause `IllegalStateException`.

For example:
if you press back so your media player released and your handler is still running and call `mediaPlayer.getDuration()`

Another Assumption is `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()`, according to open source:

```
/**
* Checks whether the MediaPlayer is playing.
*
* @return true if currently playing, false otherwise
* @throws IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been
* initialized or has been released.
*/
public native boolean isPlaying();
```